# unsigned long long to double

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, string-formatting

I am trying to convert an `unsigned long long` to a `double`, because I need the comma.

```
NSFileManager* fMgr = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSError* pError = nil;
NSDictionary* pDict = [ fMgr attributesOfFileSystemForPath:NSHomeDirectory() error:&pError ];
//get DiskSpace
NSNumber* pNumAvail = (NSNumber*)[ pDict objectForKey:NSFileSystemSize ];
[fMgr release];
//byte to Mega byte
unsigned long long temp = [pNumAvail unsignedLongLongValue]/1000000;
//Mega byte to kilo byte
double tempD = (double)(temp/1000.0);
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%qu", temp]); //result 63529
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", tempD]); //result 1168231105 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////but i want 63.529
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mismatching your format specifier.  You need to use a floating-point format to print a `double`. Try using `%f` instead of `%i`.  The mismatch causes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

I think your format is wrong. You should use `%f` : `NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", tempD]);`

Comment: Also, a megabyte is 1024 * 1024 bytes!